# Crash reporter in jira (iPhone Application) is not working

Tags: objective-c, jira, crash-reports, jira-mobile-connect

I integrated Jira mobile connect(JMV) and installed crashreport SDK in my iOS app.But when my application crashes it does not post crash report to JIRA.Before some days it ask user to you want to send report to user or not in Alert View and when user choose yes then previous crash report will be posted to Jira.But it is not working now.

Anyone know the answer? Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: what does debug log say ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor : It simply does not say anything..When app crashes then next time it is not posting crash report to jira.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor:I am novice to JVM SDK and xcode..so how can see debug log?

Comment: when you run an App in Xcode, console will output debug log. Backtrace will be shown when the app is crashed .

Comment: @Shivan Raptor: I am crashing app intensionally.. My problem is not crashing app but crash report is not posted on jira.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now this problem is solved because i forgot to enable Jira Mobile Connect feature on Jira setting Page. And also added correct ApiKey in app delegate file.